# Highcharts: Longer pie labels are chopped off

Tags: highcharts, label, long-integer, pie-chart

We recently made the switch from JFreeCharts to Highcharts. And our apps teams build small pie charts (fit in 250 by 400 px) on a dashboard, that usually show less than 8 slices. The pie labels are verbose. Highcharts usually clips them off is what I am seeing.

JSFiddle: jsfiddle.net/9tqSn/18/

It is close to what we see on our system even with word wrapping and such. Our customers also hate the fact that the chart size shrinks when labels are long. Do you plan to have a solution to better fit labels in the plot area?

We are running highcharts-3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is known bug in Highcharts, see [this report](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1581).

[Here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/223) you can find discussion about positioning dataLabels.

Comment: The acknowledged bug was "solved" in Highcharts 3.+ according to the developers.

Comment: Sadly yes, that's why I used the quotes around 'solved'. Very strange that such an expensive library doesn't fix something like this.

Comment: I don't understand you a little. "Solved" != Open ;) Open means open. And regarding issue - we are going to implement new algorithm for positioning dataLabels for pie. Probably after Highcharts 4.0 release.

Comment: Ah, I took someones comment on a form as if it came from a developer for Highcharts, but you are one of them.